# Return a User if it exists, otherwise inserting if email address Option is present

Tags: scala

If I have an email, I want to either get the user by email if it exists.  If it doesn't exist, I want to insert and return the User.

```
val userOptFut: Future[Option[User] = emailOpt.map { email =>
      userDao.getByEmail(email).map { maybeUserFut =>
        maybeUserFut match {
          case Some(u) => Future.successful(Some(u))
          case None =>
            userDao.insert(User(....)) // Future[User]
        }
      }
    }.getOrElse(Future.successful(None))
```

Where `userDao.getByEmail(..)` returns `Future[Option[User]]`

I am not sure what is wrong, but for some reason it says I am return a `Object` and not a User.

> expression of type Future[Object] does not conform to expected type
>   Future[Option[User]]

What is wrong with the above?

Comment: `getOrElse(None)`? So if the get fails you return `None`? That doesn't conform to type `Future[Option[User]]` (and I suspect that if the get succeeds it won't conform either).

Comment: @jwvh I updated my Q with updates, now it says Future[Object]

Answer (score 1):

It's really difficult with nesting like that to match the types up correctly everywhere.  What the compiler ends up doing is inferring the most specific type it can, which is `Object`, and that doesn't match your declared types.

It really helps to break down your functions into smaller pieces, with fewer levels of nesting, so the types are much more difficult to mess up.  I would do it something like the following:

```
// This is very close to Future.sequence, but Option isn't a subclass
// of TraversableOnce.  There's probably an existing function to do 
// this in a library like cats or scalaz.
def toFutureOption[A](in: Option[Future[A]]): Future[Option[A]] = in match {
  case Some(fut) => fut map {Some(_)}
  case None      => Future.successful(None)
}

def getOrInsert(email: String): Future[User] =
  userDao.getByEmail(email) transformWith {
    case Success(Some(user))        => Future.successful(user)
    case Success(None) | Failure(_) => userDao.insert(User(email))
  }

val userOptFut: Future[Option[User]] =
  toFutureOption(emailOpt map getOrInsert)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the two branches of your `match` statement don't return the same type:

```
case Some(u) => u // User
case None => userDao.insert(User(....)) // Future[User]
```

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you could do something like this:

```
case Some(u) => Future.successful(Some(u))
```

The `.getOrElse` at the end may not be suitable for your type either.

Comment: I think the None part is the issue now, since it is Future[User] and I need Future[Option[User]]

Comment: You should add some variables into your code to figure out what types you are dealing with.  For example assign a val for the whole `userDAO...` part and see what type that is returning.  `getOrElse` is supposed to be called on an `Option` type.